# Scrape a jpg file on webpage, then saving it using python

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, jpeg, python-requests

OK I'm trying to scrape jpg image from Gucci website. Take this one as example.

http://www.gucci.com/images/ecommerce/styles_new/201501/web_full/277520_F4CYG_4080_001_web_full_new_theme.jpg

I tried urllib.urlretrieve, which doesn't work becasue Gucci blocked the function. So I wanted to use requests to scrape the source code for the image and then write it into a .jpg file.

```
image = requests.get("http://www.gucci.com/images/ecommerce/styles_new/201501/web_full/277520_F4CYG_4080_001_web_full_new_theme.jpg").text.encode('utf-8')
```

I encoded it because if I don't, it keeps telling me that gbk cannot encode the string.

Then:

```
with open('1.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(image)
```

looks good right? But the result is  -- the jpg file cannot be opened. There's no image! Windows tells me the jpg file is damaged.

What could be the problem?

1. I'm thinking that maybe when I scraped the image, I lost some information, or some characters are wrongly scraped. But how can I find out which?
2. I'm thinking that maybe some information is lost via encoding. But if I don't encode, I cannot even print it, not to mention writing it into a file.

What could go wrong?

Comment: I find [wget](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wget) simpler for tasks such as this

Comment: wget is still using urllib.urlretrieve, which is blocked by Gucci.com

Comment: The file is damaged because you didn't write anything. What did you expect `f.write()` to do? If you want to save the contents of the `image` response object, you need to explicitly say so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the purpose of your use of `encode`. You're not working with text, you're working with an image. You need to access the response as binary data, not as text, and use image manipulation functions rather than text ones. Try this:

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import requests

response = requests.get("http://www.gucci.com/images/ecommerce/styles_new/201501/web_full/277520_F4CYG_4080_001_web_full_new_theme.jpg")
bytes = BytesIO(response.content)
image = Image.open(bytes)
image.save("1.jpg")
```

Note the use of `response.content` instead of `response.text`. You will need to have PIL or Pillow installed to use the `Image` module. `BytesIO` is included in Python 3.

Or you can just save the data straight to disk without looking at what's inside:

```
import requests
response = requests.get("http://www.gucci.com/images/ecommerce/styles_new/201501/web_full/277520_F4CYG_4080_001_web_full_new_theme.jpg")
with open('1.jpg','wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

A JPEG file is not text, it's binary data. So you need to use the `request.content` attribute to access it.

The code below also includes a `get_headers()` function, which can be handy when you're exploring a Web site.

```
import requests

def get_headers(url):
    resp = requests.head(url)
    print("Status: %d" % resp.status_code)
    resp.raise_for_status()
    for t in resp.headers.items():
        print('%-16s : %s' % t)

def download(url, fname):
    ''' Download url to fname '''
    print("Downloading '%s' to '%s'" % (url, fname))
    resp = requests.get(url)
    resp.raise_for_status()
    with open(fname, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(resp.content)

def main():
    site = 'http://www.gucci.com/images/ecommerce/styles_new/201501/web_full/'
    basename = '277520_F4CYG_4080_001_web_full_new_theme.jpg'
    url = site + basename
    fname = 'qtest.jpg'

    try:
        #get_headers(url)
        download(url, fname)
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        print("%s '%s'" % (e, url))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

We call the `.raise_for_status()` method so that `get_headers()` and `download()` raise an Exception if something goes wrong; we catch the Exception in `main()` and print the relevant info.